# A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget error to conditional alertdialogue title

Tags: json, flutter

Here is my code

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> userRegistration() async{

// Showing CircularProgressIndicator.
setState(() {
  visible = true ;
});

// Getting value from Controller
String fname = firstNameController.text;
String lname = lastNameController.text;
String email = emailController.text;
String phoneNumber = phoneNumberController.text;
String password = passwordController.text;

// SERVER API URL
var url = 'https://url_to_api';

// Store all data with Param Name.
var data = {'firstname': fname, 'lastname': lname, 'phone': phoneNumber, 'email': email, 'password' : password};

// Starting Web API Call.
var response = await http.post(url, body: data);

// Getting Server response into variable.
var message = jsonDecode(response.body);

var prompt;

message == message['success'] ? prompt = message['success'] : prompt = message['error'];





// If Web call Success then hide the CircularProgressIndicator.
if(response.contentLength > 0){
  setState(() {
    visible = false;
  });
}

// Showing Alert Dialog with Response JSON Message.
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(prompt),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("OK"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight, child: LoginPage()));
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

}

my json response is either ["success"=>"Please check your email for your verification code"] or ["error"=>"User already exists or account not verified, please check your email"]. But the alert dialogue only works for error if i structure my ternary operation like this

```
message == message['success'] ? prompt = message['success'] : prompt = message['error'];
```

or for success if i write like this

```
message == message['error'] ? prompt = message['error'] : prompt = message['success'];
```

when it doesnt work, it throws this error:

**A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 285 pos 10: 'data != null'**

Please help a noob in an uncharted territory

Comment: May be prompt is null ! Try this Text(prompt == null ? 'Loading...':prompt)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @NaveenAvidi i tried like you suggested, the prompt is null but it is only null for when the response is success if written like `message == message['success'] ? prompt = message['success'] : prompt = message['error'];` but if i change it to this `message == message['error'] ? prompt = message['error'] : prompt = message['success'];` the success response will work fine but the error response returns null. I am not sure why this is happening like this or what I am doing wrong with the Alertdialogue